# Display pagination in product listing page in toolbar? How active pagination in magento theme ? i am using magento defualt theme ?

Tags: magento-1.8, theme, product-list, pager

I want pagination in my toolbar in product listing page. what i can change in catalog/product/list/toolbar.phtml and page/html/pager. what do change in admin side for active pagination.
any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at this link Magento pagination

EDIT:

Also you can configure some more options at: System > Configuration > Catalog > Catalog > Frontend. Follow the below image.
 [image]

It will automatically add pagination in list page.

Answer (score 1):

In admin panel , Goto `system -> Configuration -> Catalog` section

In catalog section, Click on `frontend section`

Here you can set `pagination for list & grid view`.

No need to change in `catalog/product/list/toolbar.phtml` & `page/html/pager.phtml`